# how to remove extra margins arounding a QPixmap?

Tags: qt, qpixmap

I draw a `QRectF` in the `paint` function of my class and set a `QPixmap` as brush for it. I build an object from a class containing this `QRectF`. When I put this item in my scene and set background for the scene the QRectF appears. It also occurs for a `QPixmap` that I add to the scene. What can I do to remove the extra margins?

```
void MyQgraphicsObject::paint(QPainter *painter, )
{
    QRectF rec(0,0,50,60);
    QPixmap pi(":picture/im/super.jpg");
    pi=pi.scaled(50,60);
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(pi));
    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter->drawRoundedRect(rec,10,10);
}
////////////////////
QPixmap a(":picture/im/cloud.jpg");
scene->addPixmap(a);
scene->setbackground(Qt::blue);
```

Answer (score 0):

In python:
use functions setMaximumHeight() & setMaximumHeight()
I'have just find it :)